# Prove that sets are pairwise disjoint

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Prove for every two sets $A$ and $B$ that $A − B$, $B − A$ and $A ∩ B$ are pairwise disjoint.**

I've been looking at this problem and keep thinking it isn't true every time I think I make progress.

My main issue is that $A$ and $B$ can be any sets, including themselves. If $A = B$ then $A-B=\{\}$ but also $B-A=\{\}$ so they can't be disjoint.

Obviously, I'm missing something, probably will feel dumb after I figure it out.

Comment: Empty sets are disjoint from anything, so A-B and B-A are disjoint when A=B.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be forgetting the meaning to "pairwise disjoint." Two sets $A,B$ are disjoint if

$$A \cap B = \emptyset$$

(Note that "{}" is just an alternate way of denoting $\emptyset$, and, further, that $\emptyset \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$, trivially.) More simply, two sets are disjoint if they have no elements in common.

Playing around with a few, small, trivial examples - or using Venn diagrams - might help illustrate what exactly is going on.

[image]

Note that $A$ is the *entire* left circle, $B$ is the *entire* right circle.

Comment: I absolutely did forget what "pairwise disjoint" meant. Just to clarify they are pairwise disjoint if it is more than two sets that are disjoint with each other? A-B is disjoint with B-A which is disjoint with A ∩ B. So the group is pairwise disjoint

Comment: A group of multiple sets is pairwise disjoint if you can take any pair of them and they are disjoint. For example, if we want to say $A,B,C$ are pairwise disjoint, then 

$$A \cap B = A \cap C = B \cap C = \emptyset$$

I probably should've clarified that it is only "disjoint" if you're considering two sets ("$A$ and $B$ are disjoint"), and "pairwise disjoint" if you have a bunch of each, any two of which are disjoint

Comment: Yes, sorry I rushed my response. They are only "pairwise disjoint" when a group of sets (more than 2) have no common elements between them. Regular "disjoint" only refers to two sets

Comment: It's fine, lol, I had rushed my own. But yup, that's exactly right. :)